# too_long_frame_exception: http header is larger than 8192 bytes when querying Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

**Steps:**

Install single node Elasticsearch in Docker by the guideline:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

> docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.2

> docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.2

Open ElasticSearch in browser:

> localhost:9200

**The following error appears:**

> "type": "too_long_frame_exception", "reason": "HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes"

[image]

Comment: Can you try running this and paste the output in your question: `curl -v -XGET http://localhost:9200`

Comment: @Val thank you, it's not actual anymore, the issue is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had something similar. Try to clear site data.

Comment: Thank you. It started working after clearing site storage (at the Application tab for Chrome) / in Incognito mode.